# Giving a printer a more meaningful name

Tags: windows-xp, network-printer

Is it possible in Windows XP SP2 to give your prinetr a friendly name?

I print to 10 printers, all the names look the same and usually only one is working or not backed up at any one time.

Comment: Looks like it may be a permissions issue: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/print_rename_printer.mspx?mfr=true. Note though that I only want to change it for me, not for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Printer's name are set on the printer itself or in the Windows XP shared printer's name. You can set what ever you like.

If it's in a business environment, this is different since this is managed by the print server admin.